# TensorFlow MNIST example not running with fully_connected_feed.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am able to run the `Deep MNIST Example` fine, but when running `fully_connected_feed.py`, I am getting the following error:

```
File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 19, in <module>
from tensorflow.g3doc.tutorials.mnist import input_data ImportError: No module named
g3doc.tutorials.mnist
```

I am new to Python so could also just be a general setup problem.

Comment: Can you try editing line 19 of `fully_connected_feed.py` to simply do `import input_data`? (You might need to do the same for `import mnist` on the following line as well.)

This looks like an issue with the tutorial, which requires you to be in a particular path. Changing the import statements should fix it.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a Python path issue. Assuming that the directory `tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist` is your current working directory (or in your Python path), the easiest way to resolve it is to change the following lines in fully_connected_feed.py from:

```
from tensorflow.g3doc.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.g3doc.tutorials.mnist import mnist
```

...to:

```
import input_data
import mnist
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to link the 'g3doc' directory from the github repo into the tensorflow python wheel folder. That way you don't need to change the code.