# Getting mnist import error in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

I have just started to work with tensorflow and when I try to import the mnist dataset, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/shivam/study/deep learning/tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data
```

I have checked the python path and confirmed that the mnist dataset exists in one of the python paths(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages).

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

I even tried this method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664749) but again I get a import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/shivam/study/deep learning/tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import input_data
  File "/home/shivam/study/deep learning/input_data.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
ImportError: No module named contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call your file `tensorflow.py`, call it something else. For instance `my_experiment1.py`. That should fix it!