# ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am very frustrated by this error, what I did is getting the code from tensor flow tutorial to import moist:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

However when I run the python shows:

File "/Users/kevinling/Desktop/Machine Learning/tensorflow.py", line 2, in 
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist

When I check into the directory, the file is perfectly there:

And the directory is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl9ka.png)

The input_data.py is like:

[The input_data.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJcUc.png)

Comment: This drives me crazy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import input\_data MNIST tensorflow not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664651/import-input-data-mnist-tensorflow-not-working)

Comment: I tried all those method in the above post, none of them working

Comment: "The Mnist file" link just shows the directory.  Why not open that directory and show the input_data.py file?

Comment: @user2263572 now I showed that, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename your example from "tensorflow.py" to anything else and it will work. The interpreter is trying to import the necessary files from your script.

Answer (score -3):

Did you already install tensorflow? If not, follow their [install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) or simply install using pip:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Now, make sure you are **NOT** currently in a folder where tensorflow is located, and try running your script.

```
python your_script.py
```