# MNIST Data can't be loaded: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just started learning tensorflow. After reading those stackoverflow posts, I still have problems loading MNIST dataset.

According to the official guide, the following code will work:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

However, I get errors like this:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because 
the target machine actively refused it
```

Some people on stackoverflow said that:

```
"Make sure to download the file to the tensorflow MNIST_data folder 
tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist".
```

I'm a bit confused: Does **tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist** folder already exist in my C drive? I didn't find it. Where should I create folder to store the downloaded file? Can someone provide a detailed guideline?

Thanks!

Comment: [Link to referenced stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664651/import-input-data-mnist-tensorflow-not-working). Try downloading to the `MNIST_data` folder instead of the `tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist`.

Comment: Where do I put the MINIST_data folder?

Comment: Doesn't particularly matter, maybe in the same directory as the python file, or in `/tmp/MNIST_data` for a more absolute path.