# google colab. It gives this error when I execute the training code

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

It gives this error when I execute the training code.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-08472a50f5e6> in <module>()
      6 import logging
      7 logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
----> 8 import input_data
      9 import resnet_utils
     10 import resnet_v2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'input_data'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: Just a suggestion! Please post the steps followed by you before asking it here. Also, I can see that this error has been discussed in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664651/import-input-data-mnist-tensorflow-not-working If your issue is different, please elborate!

Comment: do you have file `input_data.py` in the same folder on Colab server ?

Comment: Yes, the input_data.py file is in the Colab service.