# No module named tensorflow.python.platform

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running `tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py`. I get:

```
hiro106@hiro106-virtual-machine:~$ python tensorflow/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tensorflow/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py", line 33, in 
import tensorflow.python.platform
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.python.platform
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow MNIST example not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659424/tensorflow-mnist-example-not-running)

Comment: Thanks so much.  But, actually, I had checked the thread before, but could not solve my issue... (I think that my issue is slightly different from this one...)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me.

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"
export PYTHONPATH

Make sure to check your path with this: echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `import tensorflow` work in a Python shell?

If not, try reinstalling with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`.

For example, for TensorFlow version 1.12 with GPU support: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0`