# Where to write python script for image classifiers

Tags: python, tensorflow, terminal, classification

I am trying to learn how to retrain an image classifier using transfer learning. I am following the steps shown in [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8)

I successfully retrained the model but I come across problems in the last step where he writes python script for classifying the newly trained model. In the video, he starts writing the code at 4:18 but does not specify where. I try writing it in the docker container but it gives me the `no module named platform` error and the `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined` error. I try writing it locally in my machine and get errors as well since I do not have the dependencies installed locally. I am not sure where to write the python code for the final step in the tutorial. Any help is appreciated.

Terminal code and errors:

```
root@dbe57bdfb014:/tensorflow# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf, sys 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
ImportError: No module named platform
>>> image_path = sys.argv[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way in this case is to just use any IDE and write the python script in a .py file locally in your computer and then copy the file into the Docker container. If you do not have the tensorflow library installed locally, tensorflow specific statements like `import tensorflow as tf` will generate errors but they can be ignored since the file will end up running in the container.

Let's assume you named the .py file `myScript.py`. In order to transfer the .py file from your computer to the container, run the command: `docker cp myScript.py myContainer:/myScript.py`

Make sure you put the .py file somewhere in the container where you can easily find it. When retraining the model, make sure you run the correct script by running: 
`python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/myScript.py`
This will then point to the correct file and it will be read as if you were doing everything locally.

Check out these links for more info:

[Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 0):

Your tensorflow package in the container is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33977273/712995). I think the best way is you uninstall and [fresh install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) tensorflow again, but make sure you take the latest version ([1.4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) as of this moment).

The second error `"NameError: name 'sys' is not defined"` simply follows the first one. The statement `import tensorflow as tf` raise an error, that's why `sys` module wasn't imported.

After you get tensorflow working, you can write code in the python console, [ipython notebook](http://cs231n.github.io/ipython-tutorial/) or create [standalone python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1522564/712995).

Comment: when reinstalling tensorflow, should I still use the "gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel" command? How do I check which version I have?

Comment: I'm using a Docker container with a tensorflow image. Wouldn't the pip install commands only work if I had everything locally in my computer?

Comment: I'm surprised it's not working out of the box as well, probably because it's dev, not stable. But if I were running the container and tensorflow's got broken, the first thing I would try is reinstall it right in that container. If it fails as well, I'd go with another container. And yes, try the stable version.