# No module named tensorflow.python.platform on WSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I found [a great Medium article](https://medium.com/applied-data-science/how-to-build-your-own-world-model-using-python-and-keras-64fb388ba459) on creating a new neural network architecture that I wanted to try out. Of course, I get to the training part, and things start to fail.

I can't import TensorFlow. Whenever I do, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin   File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'
```

Well, I looked at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/374) which suggested importing in a different folder which did not work. I also tried exporting the `PYTHONPATH` variable, set to `PYTHONPATH="/home/London/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/lib/python3.5/site-packages"` and `PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"` and `PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"`, all to no avail.

[This one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36) seemed to be a language issue, which shouldn't be my problem (and if it is, I don't know what they did to fix it.)

[This one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16264) gave the same folder changing advice. [This one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18856) seemed to be an issue with someone's command, not just trying to import it. And [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/265) again suggests the setting `PYTHONPATH`. (And yes, I did see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977273/no-module-named-tensorflow-python-platform), but both the question and answer quality are lacking.)

**Any ideas as to what I could do to get TensorFlow up and running?**

(Maybe using a different install process than just pip? I have already tried installing by running `sudo pip install tensorflow`. I would still like to be able to use it with the Medium tutorial though.)

Comment: Are you using a virtual env for this python code? If not, then could you tell me the output for the commands `which python` and `whereis python`

Comment: WSL is still experimental. Why not install native Windows Python instead?

Comment: @rustyx because the tutorial has a bunch of Ubuntu commands that I didn't know how to do in Windows. (I do have native windows Python installed.)

Comment: @HarisNadeem I am using both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. In case it still helps: `which python` gives `/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/bin/python`

Comment: `whereis python` gives `python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.5-config /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/share/python /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/bin/python /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/bin/python3.5`... to be continued

Comment: `/mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe /mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python3.dll /mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python36.dll /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz`

Comment: and if you type `/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/bin/python -m pip freeze` does it list tensorflow?

Comment: I do agree with @rustyx, why not just do it via VMWare?

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow do you have?

Comment: @HarisNadeem, MatiasVeldenegro: tensorflow==1.7.0

Comment: @HarisNadeem I need the max amount of memory I can have to be running these projects, and virtual machines I've found run slow and are a slight hassle to set up.  I'd rather do it just right on my computer where all my commands and things I'm used to are right here.

Comment: Can you try updating the version with `sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`. Latest is 1.8 but this will update it to the latest 1.7 hopefully. Source : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: @HarisNadeem I got back `tensorflow-1.7.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: I also get back `You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.` but when I try to upgrade it tells me `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/worldmodels/lib/python3.5/site-packages (10.0.1)` which is odd.

Comment: Oh weird, okay, `sudo pip` is version 8, but just `pip` is version 10. Something very odd is going on here. I'm working on installing Tensorflow 1.8 using `pip`.

Comment: Alright, it looks like doing `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by typing

`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`

@ProQ does a better job explaining how they were able to resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was some other weird stuff going on. The biggest thing I noticed that was odd is that `sudo pip --version` gave a different version than just `pip --version`.

Doing `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl` upgraded and allowed me to import tensorflow. (Note that doing `sudo pip` did not work.)

Thank you [@HarisNadeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9524896/haris-nadeem) for the solution and for helping diagnose the issue!