# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

When I import tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I don't get an error. However, I do get the error below. I'm using spyder if that helps.

As per other questions, I ensured up to date (v1.8) tensorflow using both conda and then pip installs. This didn't resolve the issue. Please assist.

```
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'
```

Comment: go to the place where tensorflow has been installed and check whether example folder exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes on downloading the TF, the example directory might not be available. You could rectify it by linking the 'example' directory from the GitHub repo into the tensorflow python wheel folder. That way you don't need to change the code.

If this doesn't work, try to replace `import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data` as `import input_data` as mentioned in the link:
[TensorFlow MNIST example not running with fully_connected_feed.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659424/tensorflow-mnist-example-not-running-with-fully-connected-feed-py)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks. After deleting various installations and reinstalling tensorflow, dask and numpy eventually it corrected itself. I'm not sure what actually sorted it out.

Answer (score 28):

I think you should use like bellow on tensorflow 2

```
import tensorflow_datasets
mnist = tensorflow_datasets.load('mnist')
```

Comment: ugn! Now I've got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'` lol

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck - You then need to install the package with `pip install tensorflow_datasets`. Done

Answer (score 10):

Use the following, it will download the data. It is from the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan)

```
import tensorflow as tf
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

To load the mnist dataset in Tensorflow 2.0:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Here is the reference:
[TensorFlow 2 quickstart for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)

Another method(also works for locally saved dataset):

```
DATA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz'

path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('mnist.npz', DATA_URL)
with np.load(path) as data:
  train_examples = data['x_train']
  train_labels = data['y_train']
  test_examples = data['x_test']
  test_labels = data['y_test']
```

Here is the reference:
[Load NumPy data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy#load_from_npz_file)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the TensorFlow examples are not pre-downloaded, so you might need to run the below command to install the examples from Github using the below code.

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
```

Answer (score 1):

**Different** approach
OS: Windows

**copy from:**

> https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/tensorflow_examples

**to**

> [python folder]\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_examples

**use**

```
import tensorflow_examples
```

**example**

```
from tensorflow_examples.models import pix2pix
```

**but for datasets use:**

```
pip install tensorflow_datasets
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding `**tutorial**` directory into `tensorflow_core`, usually this issue pops up when lacking of this file

1. `..\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\examples` check this directory to see if you have `tutorials` file.
   [lack of tutorial file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kseme.jpg)
2. If you do not have, then go to `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow` download the zip file, and extract all (or open it).
   [download tutorial file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow47z.jpg)
3. find tutorials file from `tensorflow-master\tensorflow\examples\`, and copy it to `..\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\examples`.
4. Issue resolved.
   [run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Iyz.jpg)

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
im = mnist.train.images[1]
im = im.reshape(-1, 28)
plt.imshow(im)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on Mac, simply copy the official examples to tensorflow_core/examples directory.

1. pull the tensorflow code

   `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
2. copy the examples to the system python3 directory

   `cp -a tensorflow/examples/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/examples/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the data sets to use it.

**Command:**

```
pip install tensorflow-datasets
```

**Code part:**

```
mnist_train = tfds.load(name="mnist", split="train")
```

You are done now. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download the lost files and copy them to the tensorflow-core/ examples.

for me on windows 10 is :
C:\Users\Amirreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\examples

Answer (score 0):

This folder has been deleted at September/2020. See [their repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/c31acd156cfa5f9d10d385a8ad0d0c301017dcfe/tensorflow/examples/tutorials).

I used the commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
tensorflow> git checkout c31acd156c
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing Keras according to this answer from different question:

I didn't have Keras installed and had to add it manualy

[ImportError: No module named 'keras'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271344/importerror-no-module-named-keras?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)