# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples' tensorflow version 1, 2 distracted me

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I tried to import some examples from *mnist* in *tensorflow* version 2.
But the examples are all about tensorflow version 1 and I modifed my tensorflow using

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

here, I tried to use

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

but `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'` appeared in my VSCode terminal, so I tried with

```
from keras import Sequential
from tensorflow import keras
import os
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

In this way, data loading was successful but the example code,

```
batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.next_batch(100)
```

did not work.

To get the tutorial folder in my tensorflow, I also tried to download from github, but there was no tutorial folder according to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313441/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-examples)

However, there was no folder named tensorflow_core in my `C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages`

help me

Comment: Just use [an up-to-date tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials), there is no reason to be using TF1 for MNIST.

Answer (score 0):

`tensorflow.example` is no longer in use and most of the these datasets are available in [TF datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets) library which can be accessible by using `tensorflow.keras.datasets` api.

You can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) for the same example code where you just need to replace the `fashion_mnist` dataset with `mnist` to access mnist dataset.

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

It is recommended to use `Tensorflow 2.x` with the latest version. So please update the tensorflow version to `2.x`.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow  # to install upgraded tensorflow version
```

To access few example code:

```
train_labels = train_labels[:1000]
test_labels = test_labels[:1000]
```